# RxJava Observable join() what is a good use case

Tags: rx-java2

im searching for a good example easy to understand on what the [join command](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/join.html) really does.

it seems its similar to other combined functions like zip or combineLatest perhaps but it mentions having a window of time that it can join... can anyone give a real world example of how to use it ?

i tried so far something like this:

```
Observable.just(1,2,3).join(Observable.just(4,5,6,7))
```

but this does not compile.its asking for a leftEnd and a rightEnd functions. but i'm confused what i need to do here and the documentation is a bit confusing.

Comment: In 10 years I have never encountered a problem which would need this particular operator or its dataflow pattern. You'd have to define create an observable for each value of each side (for example, `left -> Observable.timer(left, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`) to define how long it should be available for cross-combinations.